# DSquery user -office unknown parameter

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

I'm trying to lookup a username from `dsquery` using the `office` parameter as we store IDs inside of the office parameter.

Any ideas on how to get their username?

I tried

`dsquery user -office "IDHERE"`

but I got an unknown parameter error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dsquery` does not have an attribute `office`. `dsget` does.

Something like this (untested) should to the job:

```
dsquery user -limit 0 | dsget user -full -office
```

Comment: Good idea. Saved my day!

Comment: So in the end I did the following command PS C:\Windows\system32> dsquery user -name * -limit 0
| dsget user -upn -display -office >> E:\output\output.txt